# What to do when result from pipe is not last argument in next command

Tags: bash, pipe

The example below shows what I want to do, namely take the result from my last pipe and put it into the middle of the next command (where I wrote `$RESULT_FROM_FIND_COMMAND`).

```
$ find . -name "*0.01*txt" | cp $RESULT_FROM_FIND_COMMAND $(awk '{{split($1,a,"/")} {print a[3]"_"a[4]"_"a[5]}}')
```

What variable or command must I use to achieve this?

I'm using bash if that matters.

Ps. note that awk should also take the result from find as an input.

Comment: Could probably do this with a `for i in $(find . -name "*0.01*txt") do ...`, but I would like a version that follows the format above.

Comment: What about `find . -name "*0.01*txt" | awk '{split($1,a,"/"); print "echo cp "$1" "a[3]"_"a[4]"_"a[5]}' | sh`? (If satisfied by the output, remove the “echo” to perform copying.)

Comment: What's wrong with `-exec` on the find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, use the shell to iterate

```
find . -name "*0.01*txt" | while IFS= read -r filename; do
    newname=$(awk '{split($1,a,"/"), print a[3]"_"a[4]"_"a[5]}' <<< "$filename")"
    cp "$filename" "$newname"
done
```

In general, xargs is helpful:

```
find .... -print0 | xargs -o -I FILE someCommand arg1 FILE arg3 FILE
```